# Castle Windsor registering open generics ILogger

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor, simple-injector, open-generics

I have Simple Injector registration of my:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogManager),
c => typeof(LogManager<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
Lifestyle.Singleton,
c => true);
```

I need to register same LogManager in different project using Castle Windsor.

I have tried

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ILogger))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(Log4NetLogger<>).MakeGenericType())
            .LifeStyle.Singleton.Start());
```

Cannot make it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is more complicated with Castle. But you can achieve the same result with SubDependencyResolver:

```
public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof(ILogger);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var logger = typeof(LogManager<>).MakeGenericType(model.Implementation);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(logger);
    }
}
```

than add it into the kernel:

```
Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LoggerResolver())
```

Another way is to use GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy. This one will work  also in situation if LogManager has some dependencies:

```
public class OpenGenericAncestorMatchingStrategy : IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy
{
    public Type[] GetGenericArguments(ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
    {
        return new[] { context.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation };
    }
}
```

and registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>().ImplementedBy(typeof(LogManager<>), new OpenGenericAncestorMatchingStrategy()));
```

Comment: What if LogManager<T> has dependencies??